# How can I emit custom metrics from a Cadence workflow or activity?

Tags: cadence-workflow

Cadence emits a bunch of metrics using tally. Is it possible to emit my own metrics using Cadence SDK?

Go SDK has `cadence.GetMetricsScope().Counter(counterName).Inc()` but it doesn’t seem to work when I just call it. Am I missing some required configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own metrics using both the Go and Java SDKs. The following examples show how to do it using the Go SDK, and Java SDK isn’t much different than it.

In workflow code:

```
cadence.GetMetricsScope().Counter(counterName).Inc(1)
```

In activity code:

```
cadence.GetActivityMetricsScope().Counter(counterName).Inc(1)
```

However, just doing that will not be sufficient to actually emit the metrics. The reason is that tally uses `tally.NoopScope` by default, which does nothing as the name implies. Therefore, you’d also need to set up the `MetricsScope` as part of the `WorkerOptions` as in the following example:

```
workerOptions := cadence.WorkerOptions{
 MetricsScope: myTallyScope, 
}
worker := cadence.NewWorker(service, domain, taskList, workerOptions)
```

You can create `myTallyScope` by following the examples in tally documentation for [Go](https://github.com/uber-go/tally) and [Java](https://github.com/uber-java/tally).